# How to plot a graph based on a txt file and split data by words?

Tags: arrays, numpy, matplotlib, text-files

Single row of my output txt file is looks like :

```
   1          open       0   heartbeat       0      closed       0
```

The gap between data are randomly mixture with different number of \t and space. 
I wrote some code like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("../testResults/star-6.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.split('\n')

x = [row.split'HOW?')[0] for row in data]
y = [row.split('HOW?')[8] for row in data]

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title("diagram")    
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')

ax1.plot(x,y, c='r', label='the data')

leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

Which obviously does not work . is there anyway I could do sort of row.spilit_by_word ?

I am appreciate for any helps ! Thanks ..

Comment: You might want to change the title and the tags for your question, as it is not really related to matplotlib, but rather to basic string manipulations in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas`.  Given this data file (I call it "test.csv"):

```
   1          open       0   heartbeat       8      closed       0
  2          Open       1   h1artbeat       7      losed       10
   3        oPen       0   he2rtbeat       6      cosed       100
   4          opEn     1   hea3tbeat       5      clsed       10000
   5          opeN       0   hear4beat       4      cloed       10000
   6          OPen       1  heart5eat       3      closd       20000
   7          OpEn       0   heartb6at    2      close       2000
   8          OpeN       1   heartbe7t       1    osed       200
   9          oPEn       0   heartbea8       0   lsed       20
```

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\s+', header=False)
df.columns=['x',1,2,3,4,5,'y']

x=df['x']
y=df['y']
```

The rest is the same.

You could also just do:

```
ax = df.plot(x='x', y='y', title='diagram')

ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to first replace the `\t` characters to spaces and then split on the spaces:

```
row.replace('\t',' ').split()
```

otherwise (e.g. if you have more types of delimiter or very long rows) using `re` might be better:

```
re.split('\s*', row)
```

obviously you need to do `import re` first.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to decide which one is the best answer , since @TheBlackCat gives a more specific answer and it looks much simpler then directly use matplotlib I think his answer will be better for beginners like me who can see this question in future. 
However based on @hitzg's suggestion I worked out my source code for share.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


filelist = ["mesh-10","line-10","ring-10","star-10","tree-10","tri-graph-10"]
fig = plt.figure()
for filename in filelist:
    with open("../testResults/%s.log" %filename) as f:
        data = f.read()
    data = data.replace('\t',' ')
    rows = data.split('\n')
    rows = [row.split() for row in rows]

    x_arr = []
    y_arr = []
    for row in rows:
        if row:  #important : santitize null rows -> cause error
            x = float(row[0])/10
            y = float(row[8])
            x_arr.append(x)
            y_arr.append(y)

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ax1.set_title("result of all topologies")    
    ax1.set_xlabel('time in sec')
    ax1.set_xlim([0,30]) #set x axis limitation
    ax1.set_ylabel('num of mydist msg')

    ax1.plot(x_arr,y_arr, c=np.random.rand(4,1), label=filename)

    leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

Hope it helps , many thanks to both @TheBlackCat and @hitzg, best wishes to people who are new to matplotlib and trying to find an answer of this  :)